# Is the right-hand side of the canonical commutation relation an operator?

Tags: operators, commutator

Is $i\hbar$ in canonical commutation relation, $$[x,p]=i\hbar,$$ an operator? like the result of $[L_x,L_y]$. If not, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we speak of the commutator of operators $\hat A$ and $\hat B$, we say that,

$$[\hat A,\hat B] = \hat C$$

to mean that $[\hat A,\hat B]$ acting on a suitably chosen function $f$ is equivalent to $\hat C f$. This is why when computing a commutator, it is often sensible to evaluate it as $[\hat A,\hat B]f$.

In this case, $i\hbar$ is a constant, but an operator can be defined as an operator which operates by multiplying a test function by a constant. This fits the usual definition since it maps objects of the space to other members of the same space.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is an operator, it is $i \hbar$ times the *identity operator* on your Hilbert space, often just written as *1* or even left away.